# ELIXIR: how to Filter a list for a specific struct

Tags: list, pattern-matching, elixir

Given a list of items, how may we filter for a specific struct?

Example:

We need only `%TL.DocumentAttributeFilename{}` from the items in the list

```
 lst1 = [%TL.DocumentAttributeImageSize{h: 1280, w: 960}, %TL.DocumentAttributeFilename{file_name: "422305695_81769.jpg"}]
 lst2 = [%TL.DocumentAttributeVideo{duration: 7, h: 224, w: 264}, %TL.DocumentAttributeFilename{file_name: "animation.gif.mp4"}, %TL.DocumentAttributeAnimated{}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `for` for this:

Given:

```
defmodule A do
  defstruct [letter: :a]
end

defmodule B do
  defstruct [letter: :b]
end
```

You can do:

```
iex(1)> list = [%A{}, %B{}, %A{}, %A{}, %B{}]
[%A{letter: :a}, %B{letter: :b}, %A{letter: :a}, %A{letter: :a}, %B{letter: :b}]
iex(2)> for %A{} = a <- list, do: a
[%A{letter: :a}, %A{letter: :a}, %A{letter: :a}]
```

This works because `for` ignores all items that don't match the given pattern.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Enum.filter` and pattern match using function with multiple bodies:

```
list = [%A{number: 1}, %B{number: 2}, %A{number: 3}, %A{number: 4}, %B{number: 5}, %A{number: 6}]

Enum.filter(list, fn
  %A{} -> true
  _ -> false
end)
```

This is particularly useful because you can further narrow down using item's properties and guards:

```
Enum.filter(list, fn
  %A{number: n} when n > 4 -> rem(n, 3) == 0
  %B{number: n} when n < 2 -> true
  _ -> false
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Enum.filter` to make it clearer what operation takes place:

```
Enum.filter( lst1, fn( x ) -> %TL.DocumentAttributeFilename{} == x end )
```

As Dogbert observed the above expression will keep only those elements of `lst1` that are `TL.DocumentAttributeFilename` structs with default field values - not what you asked for.

Here's a version that will keep all `TL.DocumentAttributeFilename` structs of `lst1`:

```
Enum.filter( lst1, fn( x ) -> x.__struct__ == TL.DocumentAttributeFilename end )
```

Comment: This will only match if `x` has the default values for all fields of the struct `TL.DocumentAttributeFilename`.